how to create merkle root of given hashes inside a pallet
I need to create merkle root of given hashes.
pub type MmrRootHash = H256;
pub fn create_merkle_root(leaves: Vec<MmrRootHash>) -> MmrRootHash {
            ..
        }


Is there any library or example, which I can refer?

Do you want to have a MMR or a merkle tree root?

@bkchr I want to create merkle root of leaves.

The following code should do it:
sp_runtime::traits::BlakeTwo256::trie_root(
    leaves
        .iter()
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(i, l)| ((i as u32).encode(), l.encode()))
        .collect()
);

